Powershell question regarding the formatting of output into a new file
I am in the process of learning how to use Powershell. I am working on a problem where I am supposed to A) Display the files within another folder on the screen in tabular format,B) Create a new text file, and C) put the info displayed from B into the new next file.
I have figured out how to do it all correctly except for the last part, C. The folder is created and is listing each file as it should. However, it isn't showing Length and LastWriteTime inside of the text file like a tabular format, just the name of each folder.
My code so far is:
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\ | format-table Name, Length, LastWriteTime -AutoSize
New-Item C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\ -Name 'NewFile.txt' -ItemType File
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\ | Set-Content C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\NewFile.txt

Any help would be appreciated.

As noted in the 'Set-Content' help files:
Notes

Set-Content is designed for string processing. If you pipe non-string
objects to Set-Content, it converts the object to a string before
writing it. To write objects to files, use Out-File.

That means that your code is actually equivalent to:
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\ | 
foreach ToString |
Set-Content C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\NewFile.txt

In that is the result you see.
So, as Microsoft recommends, you should use 'Out-File' instead of 'Set-Content' like this:
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\ |
Out-File C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\NewFile.txt

BTW, if you use 'Out-File' you don't need to create the txt file first.
Another solution is to use Out-String to preserve the console-type output, like this:
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\ | 
Out-String |
Set-Content C:\Users\LabAdmin\Desktop\Folder1\NewFile.txt


Thank you so much! I wasn't even aware Out-File existed.

@Showtunes Please, if my answer solved your problem except it and upvote it. Thanks
